# How To Restrict Payment Gateways/Options based on User Account or Membership Type?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

Sometimes, certain individuals choose 'Pay Later' on our registration forms, and do not pay. We would like to 'flag' these individuals so the pay later option is automatically removed from the form.

Also, in general, it would be nice to show/hide payment gateways based on user ID, membership type, etc. like Drupal Commerce allows.

Is there any way to handle this in CiviCRM 4.7?